# Customizing React-Native SectionList search bar for various layouts

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-native, user-interface

I am using SectionList for the ListView in my react-native application but I am struggling to customize the search bar for different layouts, I have to put an icon on the right hand side of the search bar which I managed to do it by using the below code but the 90% width doesn't seems to fit properly on larger devices(i.e., iPad), I mean there is extra space between searchbar and icon, I am not sure how to make it work consistently on all devices.

Code used:

```
<View>
  <SectionList
    data={testData}
    searchBarPlacholder={'test'}
    noResultsMessageCode={testData}
    searchBarWidth={'90%'}
    renderItem={testData}
    dataToSectionsHandler={testData}
    renderSectionHeader={testData}
    onSearchChange={testData}
  />
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <Image
      source={require('../testData.png')}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the styling for the same like where the styles have been applied?

Comment: there is no stylings related to the code, except the height/width of image

Comment: Can anyone help me on this, I tried putting flexDirection row as well, both search and  icon fits properly but it creates a white space on the right hand side of the list with the width similiar to the right icon